# drawLinearGradient(), but for solid colour

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics, drawrect

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` class, and within that I've overridden the `drawRect` method to produce a nice gradient background. However, I only want the gradient for one case, and I switch using an `if` statement.

Is there a better way to write this?

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Setup gradient
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGColorRef topColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    CGColorRef bottomColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:240.0/255.0 green:240.0/255.0 blue:240.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;

    CGRect cellRect = self.bounds;

    if (!isDescription)
        drawLinearGradient(context, cellRect, topColor, bottomColor);
    else
        drawLinearGradient(context, cellRect, bottomColor, bottomColor); 

}
```

It seems silly drawing a gradient when I want a solid. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you had a look at Apple's Quartz2D reference material to find an alternative?

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't really sure where in the reference material to look as this is the first Quartz code I've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at CGContextFillRect here: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html

You will need to set bottomColor as the fill color first